# Java Netbeans 8.0 Jframe GUI program - each index value in arraylist is not being displayed on individual line in jtextArea

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe

I am working on another program in my course, and we were supposed to create a program that performs multiple functions with an arraylist of integers (i.e marks of a class). My problem is that when I try to output the values of the "marks" arraylist in ascending order, with each value being on its own line, it only displays the value that was most recently inputted.

For example, if I input 25 and then 54 and I click the "sort" button, only 54 is displayed in the Jtextarea. My code is shown below, and note the problem is inside the sortButtonActionPerformed method.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MarksGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList <Integer> marks = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList <Integer> marksSorted = new ArrayList();

    int numlvlR=0;
    int numlvl1=0;
    int numlvl2=0;
    int numlvl3=0;
    int numlvl4=0;


    public MarksGUI() {

        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        titleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        markLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        markInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        addButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        analyzeField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        classmarksField = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        sortButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        analyzeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        titleLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        titleLabel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204));
        titleLabel.setText("Marks Program");

        markLabel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        markLabel.setText("Student Mark:");

        addButton.setText("Add");
        addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        analyzeField.setEditable(false);
        analyzeField.setColumns(20);
        analyzeField.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(analyzeField);

        classmarksField.setEditable(false);
        classmarksField.setColumns(20);
        classmarksField.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(classmarksField);

        sortButton.setText("Sort");
        sortButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sortButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        analyzeButton.setText("Analyze");
        analyzeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                analyzeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(42, 42, 42))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(107, 107, 107)
                        .addComponent(titleLabel))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(75, 75, 75)
                        .addComponent(markLabel)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(markInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(addButton)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(sortButton)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(analyzeButton)
                .addGap(90, 90, 90))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(titleLabel)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(markInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(markLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(addButton))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 245, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(sortButton)
                    .addComponent(analyzeButton))
                .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    //add method is working/////////////
    private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        int newMarks;

        newMarks = Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText());

        marks.add(newMarks);
        System.out.println(marks);//testing purposes




    }                                         
    //problem is in sort method//////////////
    private void sortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        int biggestMark = largestMark();//YOU WERE HERE///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for(int k = 0;k<marks.size();k++)
        {

            marksSorted.add((marks.get(k)));
            System.out.println(marksSorted);//testing purposes

        }
        for(int x = 0;x<marks.size();x++)
        {
            Collections.sort(marksSorted);
            classmarksField.setText(marksSorted.get(x)+"\n");
            System.out.println(marksSorted);//testing purposes
        }

    }**                                          
    //working//////////////////////
    private void analyzeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        int maxMark, minMark, mark;
        analyzeField.setText("Class Average:"+classAverage()+"\n"+"Maximum Mark:"+largestMark()+"\n"+"Mininmum Mark:"+smallestMark()+"\n"+"Range of Marks:"+rangeofMarks()+"\n"+"Num at level 4:"+numlvl4+"\n"+"Num at level 3"+numlvl3+"\n"+"Num at level 2:"+numlvl2+"\n"+"Num at level 1:"+numlvl1+"\n"+"Num at level R:"+numlvlR);









    }                                             
    public int classAverage(){
        int marksTotal, marksAverage;
        marksTotal = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<marks.size();i++){
            marksTotal = marksTotal+marks.get(i);
        }
        marksAverage = marksTotal/marks.size();
        return(marksAverage);   
    }
    public int smallestMark(){
        int smallestmarkValue;
        smallestmarkValue = 100;
        for(int y = 0; y<marks.size();y++){
            if(marks.get(y)<=smallestmarkValue)
            {
                smallestmarkValue = marks.get(y);
            }
            else
            {   
            }
        }
        return(smallestmarkValue);
    }
    public int largestMark(){
        int largestmarkValue;
        largestmarkValue = 0;
        for(int z = 0; z<marks.size();z++){
            if(marks.get(z)>=largestmarkValue)
            { 
                largestmarkValue = marks.get(z);
            }
            else
            {
            }

        }
        return(largestmarkValue);     
    }
    public int rangeofMarks(){
        int range;
        range = largestMark()-smallestMark();
        return(range);
    }
    public int numwitheachlevel(){
        int mark;
        mark = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j<marks.size();j++){
            mark = marks.get(j);
            if(mark<50)
            {
                numlvlR++;
            }
            else if((mark >= 50) && (mark < 60))
            {
                numlvl1++;
            }
            else if((mark >= 60) && (mark < 70))
            {
                numlvl2++;
            }
            else if((mark >= 70) && (mark < 80))
            {
                numlvl3++;
            }
            else if(mark >= 80)
            {
                numlvl4++;
            }

        //numeachlvl.addAll(numlvlR,numlvl1,numlvl2,numlvl3,numlvl4);
        //return(numeachlvl);//you were here///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }
    //System.out.println("Range:"+rangeofMarks());
    System.out.println("Largest mark"+largestMark()); 
    System.out.println("Smallest mark:"+smallestMark());
    System.out.println("Number at level R:"+numlvlR);
    System.out.println("Number at level 1:"+numlvl1);
    System.out.println("Number at level 2:"+numlvl2);
    System.out.println("Number at level 3:"+numlvl3);
    System.out.println("Number at level 4:"+numlvl4);

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]){
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MarksGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MarksGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MarksGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MarksGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MarksGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton analyzeButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea analyzeField;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea classmarksField;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField markInput;
    private javax.swing.JLabel markLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton sortButton;
    private javax.swing.JLabel titleLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Also the numwitheachlevel() method is not working as I want it to. If the mark falls within a certain range, a value of 1 is supposed to be added  to the previous value of the variable. This is why I have "numlvlR++;", so that one is added to the variable when a person has a mark within the range.

Comment: Please create and post a valid [mcve]. There's no need to require folks to go through a ton of unrelated code when the problem can and should be distilled down to its essentials. Please read the link to fully understand just what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> . For example, if I input 25 and then 54 and I click the "sort" button, only 54 is displayed in the Jtextarea

```
for(int x = 0;x<marks.size();x++)
{
    Collections.sort(marksSorted);
    classmarksField.setText(marksSorted.get(x)+"\n");
    System.out.println(marksSorted);//testing purposes
}
```

Why are you using `marks.size` to control the loop if you are getting the data from the `markssorted` List. The sort does not create a copy of the data.

Why would you sort the List every time through the loop? What do you expect to change?

Why would you use setText(...)? That replaces all the text in the text area so you only get the last value in the List.

Use the `append(...)` method of the JTextArea.

Comment: I fixed that, now I am trying to return an ArrayList in one of my methods. It it giving me the error "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 0".

Comment: I already gave you an answer. Why are you referencing 2 ArrayLists in your loop? Why is your ArrayList empty? You need to do basic debugging.